# How do I draw a simple ellipse using CoreGraphics on the iPhone (specifically iPad)?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-graphics

Just wondering how to draw an ellipse using CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect` or `CGContextFillEllipseInRect`

Comment: or CGContextAddEllipseInRect, or CGPathAddEllipse