# IOS UIView layer setCornerRadius in ellipse shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ellipse, cornerradius

I have a little doubt to make a ellipse shape using `UIView`.

My view has a dimension like `w:50.0f e h:20.0f` and using this command:

```
[[viewElement layer] setCornerRadius:w/2];
```

But the shape isn't a good shape for ellipse.

I want this:

[image: shape]

The borders of shape is distorted, can I make an ellipse shaped like which is expected?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using the height instead of the width when setting the corner radius?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
viewElement.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, w);
viewElement.layer.cornerRadius = w / 2;
viewElement.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, h / w);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to make ellipse by using `cornerRadius`. Instead of it you could draw ellipse by using [CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231902/how-do-i-draw-a-simple-ellipse-using-coregraphics-on-the-iphone-specifically-ip) function.